# Code throws warning: Undefined index in GET array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

This code shows warnings on the * marked line, so any idea without using `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` ?
Just need any alternate code...

```
$page = $_GET['page'];  // gets the variable $page ******
//global $page;

if (!empty($page)){
    include($page);
}   // if $page has a value, include it
else {
    include("home.php");
}   // otherwise, include the default page
```

And here is the warning "Notice: Undefined index: page in :\www\Apachi_xampp\setup\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 284"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please use a more intuitive question title :)

Comment: What are the errors/warnings you get? Your question is really going to get shredded.

Comment: It's a good question.  The title is fine. The problem is like he says: $_GET['page'] will return a warning if 'page' index is not found in $_GET.  So the solution is to test if it is set before attempting to retrieve the value.  Fastest way is probably to use ternary condition like Telulz or Kuipers suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because if the ?page paramater isn't set in the URL it will throw that error. Replace with the following code:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : '';  // gets the variable $page ******
//global $page;

if (!empty($page)){
    include($page);
}   // if $page has a value, include it
else {
    include("home.php");
}   // otherwise, include the default page
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it's a warning and not a NOTICE saying "unidentified index"?
Try this:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_GET['page'])){ 
     $page = $_GET['page'];
     if(!empty($page)){
       include($page);
     }else{
       include("home.php");
     }
 }
```